How to use Azure Managed Identities with Keycloak for authentication
We have a microservices-based stack that is hosted behind Nginx. We use Keycloak to authenticate the users. As identity providers in Keycloak, we have previously successfully used OpenID Connect and registered an MS Entra App. This needs Client ID and Client Secret to be configured and then users can be given necessary permissions at the MS Entra App level and those permissions can be parsed in our app after authenticating through Keycloak.
Now instead of the MS Entra App that needs client ID and secret, we wanted to move to using Azure Managed Identities (customer mandate). What parts of our app do we need to switch or modify? Is Keycloak still relevant? I have not been able to find any resources that explain how to enable this. All of our microservices are containerized in on Azure VM instance. We do not use K8s.
We read through online resources for the same.

Can you share your setup details for better clarity?

@Arko what else would you like to know?

OAUTH
Sounds like your architecture is right:

You have an authorization server (Keycloak)
You have clients that connect to the AS
You have APIs that trust tokens issued by the AS

The AS is responsible for issuing the right tokens - especially for your APIs. Your AS can also connect to one or more IDPs that manage user authentication.
WORKLOAD IDENTITIES
From a quick browse it seems that Azure managed identities are a form of workload identity that you can use to harden an OAuth implementation:

Use strong platform issued credentials that are automatically renewed for you
Restrict which components can call each other based on their component level identity

But workload identities do not authenticate users or deliver verifiable business permissions to APIs like OAuth does.
OAUTH AND WORKLOAD IDENTITIES
I have not used Azure managed identities but they feel similar to SPIFFE and SPIRE which I have used in conjunction with OAuth. There is a group called WIMSE that defines some ways to harden security:

Use platform issued client assertions to replace client secrets
Use platform issued mTLS credentials eg for a connection from an API to its database

So I believe that using Azure managed identities will not change your OAuth architecture at all.
USER DATA SOURCES
During a user login, your clients run an OpenID Connect code flow at your AS which uses Entra ID as an identity provider.
An Entra ID extensions app can act as a repository to store custom user attributes. Perhaps you configure Keycloak to retrieve these using a plain client secret and issue them to tokens?
If so then you might be able to migrate user information to a different repository that requires an Azure managed identity as a hardened credential
Other than this user data source work there should be no change to the architecture. Nothing changes in your APIs and clients.

You are correct wrt the app architecture. I am not sure how to integrate Azure Managed Identities here.

Ok - I think I get it and that you need to use a hardened credential to access sensitive user information. I updated my answer.

Yes, this is how we have it working right now. I.e. using a client secret. Is it possible to not need a secret from MS Entra and still get authenticated?
